# Keyframes not on time

Tags: animation

When I import a certain model (which doesn't come with an animation), blender creates keyframes on "odd" times. They are not placed at times 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.
Instead they are placed at 1, 1.85, 2.75, 3.5, etc.

Why is that so?

[image]

Comment: Is the animation created at a different time base (frames per second)? Make sure the blender project settings matching the original.

Comment: @susu I didn't create an animation, and there is no animation in the model when I import it.

Comment: Maybe you've played with its speed in the NLA, then moved the keyframes in the Dope Sheet, in that case even if you come back to the original, it's not aligned with the frame, it will automatically if you move them

Comment: @moonboots Thank you, but I didn't do that. I automatically happens each time I import it, even if it doesn't have any animation. The key frames are added automatically.